# Telegram MiniApps (WebView) debugging - Add developers' extension to DevTools

Tags: webview, telegram

I created a sample DevTool extension like "Hello world" that just adds a tab to DevTools panel, it appears when I launch DevTools in the browser. But when I push "Inspect" menu on the telegram mini app in Telegram Desktop, DevTools appears with a limited extension list. My self-created extention doesn't appear to add its tab. Is it a problem of telegram permissions or wrong DevTools config? Or is it not possible to debug WebView apps with 3d-party extensions?